# How can I have flutter's navigator push a route in the navigation bar instead if fullscreen

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

In Flutter, How do I push a screen so that it appears inside the tab, rather than full screen.

Here is my code:

```
Card(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text("PRIVACY POLICY", style: Styles.textDark),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => SinglePageTextView("PRIVACY POLICY", "/assets/privacy.txt"))),
  ),
)
```

PS: I have tried the fullscreenDialog setting on CupertinoPageRoute, and it does nothing!

## Source screen:

[image]

## When tapped Privacy Policy, this shows up:

[image]

## This is what I am trying to achieve (tab bar is still showing!):

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Navigator, use setState() to change the current page content to one you need.

Comment: That sounds like a hack, and an ugly one at that.

Comment: If he doesn't use Navigator there are no navigation animations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an ExpansionTile to achieve your goal?

```
ExpansionTile(
      title: Text("I'm expandable."),
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Hello, here I am."),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, Maybe will use if this can't be solved!